# Deserialize bin file from C#.NET to Objective-c or C++

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c

There is a bin file "sample.bin" that contain a list of objects in c# (serialize), is that possible to deserialize this file to c++ or objective-c?

I do not think that, but just to be sure if possible.

Comment: "Is it possible". Yes, it is always possible. Will it be worth the time to figure out .NET's binary format? Probably not.

Comment: Congratulations, you are about to learn about some of the many many reasons serialization is really hard.</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file was created with .NET serialization then it's going to almost impossible to deserialize into C++ or Objective-C. .NET serialization embeds type information and type cache information into the file which won't make sense in another language.

If you serialize between languages then take a look at [Google Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). There are implementation for most languages and platforms these days.

Comment: Yes, and this is the code in c#.Net

new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fs, myObj);

so?

Comment: @HazemAbdullah - then that's going to cause you a problem between different languages. Have a look at Google Protocol buffers, or even xml...